# Get selectors with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<span id="dsf_test"></span>
<span id="sdfdfd_test"></span>
<span id="werwerwer_test"></span>
<span id="re_test"></span>
```

How can i get all these selectors with one query? For this the best is get with end _test, but how?

```
$('#???_test')
```

Comment: Side note, this is a pretty bad approach most of the time, use a class.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

span id="dsf_test">

```
//end with selector
$('[id$="_test"]')
```

span id="mig_rrrrd">

```
//start with selector
$('[id^="mig_"]')
```

Answer (score 2):

Attribute [ends with selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/) :

```
$('[id$="_test"]')
```